# No hyphenation patterns were preloaded for the language

Tags: texlive, babel, hyphenation

My document compiles fine, except for this warning:

```
Package babel Warning: No hyphenation patterns were preloaded for
(babel)                the language `French' into the format.
(babel)                Please, configure your TeX system to add them and
(babel)                rebuild the format. Now I will use the patterns
(babel)                preloaded for \language=nohyphenation instead on input line 75.
```

I have installed TeXlive manually (using the `install-tl` script). I installed (using `tlmgr`) the packages `babel` and `babel-french`. I tried these commands without success:

```
fmtutil --all
fmtutil-sys --all
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run `tlmgr install hyphen-french`